# Swift - adding Data to core data with a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have two entities:

AgendaEvent

AgendaDate

AgendaEvent has a one to many relationship with AgendaDate (the relationship name 
is agendaDates).

Agenda Dates has just one attribute (agendaDates of type Date).

I am trying to save all the values of an array into Agendadate.

This saving could happens in two different way.

1. The user is creating a new AgendaDate (so a new context)
2. The user is updating an existing AgendaDate

This is my code:

```
var agendaDateToEdit: AgendaDate // this value is passed through a segue if the user clicked to modify an existing one.
var dateToAdd: AgendaDate!
if agendaDateToEdit == nil {
            dateToAdd = AgendaDate(context: context)
        } else {
            dateToAdd = agendaDateToEdit
        }
```

now i perform the for loop to insert the items form the array:

```
let agendaEvent: AgendaEvent!

if agendaEventToEdit != nil {
  agendaEvent = agendaEventToEdit
} else {
  agendaEvent = AgendaEvent(context:context)
}

for date in dates {
    dateToAdd.agendaDates = date
    agendaEvent.addToAgendaDates(dateToAdd)
    ad.saveContext()
 }
```

However in this way I store just the last value of the array.

I'm new to swift and i don't really understand where the error is.
I would really appreciate if anybody can help.

Thank you!

Comment: First let's do a little cleanup. `AgendaDate` ideally should have its existing attribute, `agendaDates` renamed `date`. This is because the attribute is singular not plural and it can get very confusing using the same name for an entity and one of its attributes. Next consider adding an inverse to-one relationship from `AgendaDate` back to `AgendaEvent` so you can get a date and figure out what even is happening then. These changes will make it a bit easier for others to follow what is happening in your code, which will hopefully lead to better answers.

Comment: @theMikeSwan thx for the answer. I will change the attribute name. The inverse relationship is already there...and i named it: agendaEvents. I edited my question to explain what agendaEvent is..

Answer (score 0):

`dateToAdd` is defined above the scope of the `for` loop, therefore it sticks around on each iteration of the loop…

1. You create or assign `dateToAdd`
2. First pass though the loop starts

   3. The date of `dateToAdd` is set to `date`
   4. `dateToAdd` is appended to the `agendaEvent`
   5. Context gets saved
3. Next pass through the loop starts

   7. The date is again set on `dateToAdd` (this changes the date in the copy that is already in the `agendaEvent`)
   8. `agendaEvent` is told to append the *same* `dateToAdd` it just added which it ignores as that entity is already in its list of `agendaDates`
   9. Context gets saved and the for loop continues until it runs out of dates.

To-many relationships in Core Data are stored with `NSSet` which ensures each item only exists once. That is why you only get one `AgendaDate`added to the event.

Since you hold on to the one `AgendaDate` instance and keep changing its date you see whatever the last date in the array of dates is. If you add a breakpoint to the loop you should see the one `AgendaDate` in the `AgendaEvents` gets each date in turn.

If you create a new `dateToAdd` each time through the loop I predict you will see much better results

```
for date in dates {
    let dateToAdd = AgendaDate(context: context)
    dateToAdd.agendaDates = date
    agendaEvent.addToAgendaDates(dateToAdd)
    ad.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Originally I have done it as you suggested... and work perfectly... it creates a new context every time and store the values... I was trying to have a unique context with all the values, and to update it if it already exist... but probably due to my little knowledge of core data i was trying to do something that makes no much sense...

Comment: You should have one static context that you use to create all the entities.

Comment: Assuming this is all being done in one class that class should have a property to hold the managed object context. The context should be assigned to it by whatever comes before or the context should get pulled from the the app delegate. Then you can use the property for creating all the entities.

Comment: Which i believe i do... in my Appdelegate I have: `let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext`  and in i call `agendaEvent = AgendaEvent(context:context)` when i create it the first time..

Comment: If i create every time a new context it won't work... that's because user can change the date... e.g. first time he inserted 23/09 -24/09 - 25/09, second time just 24/09 - 25/09... the 23/09 won't be overwritten and so still shown.... so i'm trying to let the user insert all the data of the array and override the existing object...

Comment: I think you would benefit from Marcus's book, https://pragprog.com/book/mzswift/core-data-in-swift. It's in Swift 3 rather than 4 but the compiler will help you with the conversion.

Comment: Thx... I'll definitely check it out!

Comment: At the end i've solved by storing an array of Date in core Data in a transformable attribute. Probably is not the most elegant way of doing it... but i really had no clue how to achieve what i needed by using the NSSet...

Comment: Sorry to wake up this thread after so long, but are their performance implications to calling .save() with each iteration of the loop? I was thinking about doing this, but I didn’t know if it would qualify as “best practice”.

Comment: Yeah, it would likely be better to save after the loop. For small arrays it won't really matter, but for something larger it could start to have an effect.